# Can't switch to graphics card(GTX1050) in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, asus

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it was giving the soft lock-up error so I pressed `E` on the boot menu and added the code `nouveau.modeset=0`, subsequently I went to **System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers** and then select the NVIDIA driver. However I went to check the settings to see if it was using the graphics card and I see that it is not:
[System is using Intel Graphics and not Nvidia graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJjfW.png)

I tried to check some settings and
[Not communicating with Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYiGk.png)
[Recommended driver is selected here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9gMy.png)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and try again.

Comment: Hey, this worked perfectly! Thanks Gabriela!